# Why is Corvo's mask Piero's greatest creation?

Tags: dishonored

In the series "Tales from Dunwall" there's an [episode about Piero.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oIgrvjkaSP8)

It states that Piero's greatest creation would be Corvo's mask. This is the guy that cured the rat plague and made a giant arc pylon and his greatest creation was a visually impressive mask with a couple of lenses in it?

It could be argued that it's the creation that had the most impact, but versus a cure for the rat plague? Seriously?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know this isn't optimal, but lacking a copy of the game at the moment, I am forced to use Wikia as the source of my information.

Now, according to Wikia, the [Arc Pylons](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Arc_Pylon) are the brainchild of Anton Sokolov. Piero perfected their schematics, true, but he didn't invent them in the strictest sense.

Same goes for the plague elixir: Anton Sokolov had devised his own version. While Piero accuses Sokolov of stealing his research, in one ending of the game they work together to develop an *actual* cure for the plague.

The mask is different: it was devised by Piero alone, after being inspired by the Outsider. This is somewhat similar to how Mendeleev develop the periodic table after allegedly dreaming about it.

The mask is not just a *couple of lenses*: it has a telescopic-like feature, that doesn't only magnify the image, but also magnifies the sound - making it a perfect spying tool. I'm sure you will agree that the mask required much more skillful craftsmanship - fitting multiple magnifying glasses with movable parts in an apparently armored casing is no easy task, even now.

As an out-of-universe note, both the plague cure and the arc pylon have some real-world prototypes (see vaccines and Tesla coils). The mask does not.

Comment: Good job! Sokolov did indeed invent the cure and arc pylon +1!